# How to Find How Many Points Fit In a Circle Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, circles

The question is the following:

> Find the center and the radius for each of the circles $x^2-2x+y^2-4y-4=0$ and $x^2-2x+y^2-4y+5=0$. How many points fit the equation $x^2-2x+y^2-4y+9=0$?

I found the radius for the first circle equation to be 3 and the center to be $(1, 2)$. The second circle equation also had the same center, but I got it to be a radius of $0$ (which looks weird of an answer to me). Here's the work that I did to get to the center and the radius for the second circle:

$$x^2-2x+y^2-4y+5=0$$
$$x^2 - 2x + (\frac{-2}{2})^2 + y^2 - 4y + (\frac{-4}{2})^2 = -5 + (\frac{-2}{2})^2 + (\frac{-4}{2})^2$$ 
$$(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 = -5 + 1 + 4$$
$$(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 = 0$$

*If there's anything wrong with my work, please let me know.*

The center that I got for the third circle equation is also $(1,2)$ and the radius of $2$. Here's my work:
$$x^2-2x+y^2-4y+9=0$$
$$x^2 - 2x + (\frac{-2}{2})^2 + y^2 - 4y + (\frac{-4}{2})^2 = -9 + (\frac{-2}{2})^2 + (\frac{-4}{2})^2$$
$$(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 = -4$$
But $\sqrt{-4} = 2i$, and I can't make that as a radius. Is there also anything that is wrong with my work for this one?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You did nothing wrong. $x^2-2x+y^2-4y+5=0$ represents a point, not a circle.

Comment: I don't know why @Landuros is talking about concentric circles in his comment; we're not intersecting the circles. Your last equation, on its own, has no solutions (no real numbers can make it true), so graphically, it is literally nothing: it contains no points at all.